# The convergence and reality of Gauss Hypergeometric Function

Tags: complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

The Gauss Hypergeometric function is defined via a power series:

$$F(a,b,c;z)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma(b+n)}{\Gamma(c+n)}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

In Abramowitz and Stegun they say the circle of convergence of this function is the unit circle $|z|=1$. I interpret that as a statement for all $a,b,c$, but the circle of convergence could be larger (not smaller) for specific choices of $a,b,c$. (correct me if that's wrong please!)

I'm working with the specific case of $F(1/2,1/2,1;x)$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The following plot from Wolfram Alpha therefore confuses me:

[image]

So the real part of this seems to conform to my understanding - it appears not converge at x=1, but the radius of convergence is larger then $|z|=1$ because of the particular parameters of my problem. But the real/complex parts confuse me:

For $x<1$, $F(1/2,1/2,1,x)$ is real (the imaginary part is not just small, as in the plot, but it's zero). However, for $x>1$, $F(1/2,1/2,1,x)$ is complex. How is that possible? How can a power series of a real variable $x$ have both real and imaginary parts?

EDIT: I don't know much about the Gamma function, but I think for any real $x$, $\Gamma(x)$ is also real, as long as $x$ is not an integer (then it doesn't exist).

Comment: Why do you think that the series converges for $|x|>1?$ The non-zero imaginary part comes from non integer powers of $(1-x)$, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.i. And Wolfram Alpha says that your function is $\frac{2}{\pi} K(x)$ where $K$ is the complete elliptic Integral of the first kind.

Comment: @gammatester: You're talking about the transformations? Ok I see that you get $(1-x)^a$ out of those, but how do you know that doing that transformation isn't "cancelled" somehow by the other term in the expression? That's why I'm sticking with the original definition; it displays my ignorance easier!

Comment: What WA is actually plotting is the analytic continuation of such hypergeometric function, namely the complete elliptic integral of the first kind: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Whoa...I had no idea it would do continuation without telling me. So what you're saying is within the circle of convergence (-1 to 1 here) the plot is showing 2F1, but outside of that region it is showing K?

Comment: @levitopher: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It can be found on Wikipedia that $$\Gamma (n) =(n-1)!$$ and $$\Gamma (n+0.5 ) =\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma (2n)}{2^{2n-1} \Gamma (n)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} (2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}(n-1)!}$$
Therefore if we denote $$a_n =\frac{\Gamma (n+0.5)^2 }{\Gamma (n+1) n! }=\frac{\pi [(2n-1)!]^2}{2^{4n-2}[(n-1)!]^2 (n!)^2}$$
Hence $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n }=\frac{\pi [(2n+1)!]^2}{2^{4n+2}[(n+1)!]^2 (n!)^2}\cdot \frac{2^{4n-2}[(n-1)!]^2 (n!)^2}{\pi [(2n-1)!]^2}=\frac{4n^2 (2n+1)^2}{2^4 n^2 (n+1)^2}\to 1$$
Thus in your case the radius of convergence is equal to $1.$